# Minimize usage of same subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following, simplified function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION upsert(varchar, varchar, varchar) RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN

with t1 as (
    select id from table_a where $1 = a_field
), t2 as (
    select id from table_a where $2 = a_field
)
insert into table_b (tba_ref, status)
values
    ((select id from t1), $3),
    ((select id from t2), $3)
on conflict on constraint uniq_constraint do
update set status =
    (CASE
    WHEN table_b.tba_ref = (select id from t1) THEN 'old'
    WHEN table_b.tba_ref = (select id from t2) THEN 'new'
    END)
;
END;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

Is there any way I can get rid of the select subqueries? This is just a simplified example which roughly mirrors the structure of the original query. The original has a lot more of those two subqueries and I would like to improve performance by storing the result once instead of running those queries repeatedly.

Comment: If this query is supposed to return one record then just store the id in a variable: `select id from table_a where $1 = a_field`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing this as two separate updates:

```
with t1 as (
      select id from table_a where $1 = a_field
    )
insert into table_b (tba_ref, status)
    values ((select id from t1), $3)),
on conflict on constraint uniq_constraint do
    update set status = 'old';

with t2 as (
      select id from table_a where $2 = a_field
    )
insert into table_b (tba_ref, status)
    values ((select id from t2), $3)),
on conflict on constraint uniq_constraint do
    update set status = 'new';
```

You can wrap these in a single transaction.

I don't think there is a way to pass "another" column in to the `on conflict` clause.  Your `insert` has no way to distinguish between the two values -- that is `'old'` and `'new'` are not being inserted into the table.